# hosting a tcp/ip server on a free nitrous.io account

Tags: nitrousio

from the faq I understand that free nitrous.io account gives us HTTP ports so we can host http related stuff. I want to get some guidance, if possible, on how can I run a piece of code which is running and listening on a specific allowed tcp/ip port inside of a nitrous.io free account linux vm, so I can connect it from any outside pc on internet. Right now I can compile my code and run tcp/ip server inside the vm, say on port 3000, but I dont know on how to connect to it from my home laptop.
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

just copy/paste the URL from the 'preview -> port 3000' option in nitrous. As long as your nitrous box hasn't shut down due to inactivity you'll be able to reach it from anywhere on the web.